# play sound by clicking on Imagebutton

Tags: android

i try to play an audio file by clicking on an imagebutton for this i use the following code:

```
ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ba);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            //TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mpButtonClick.start();
        }
    });
```

but by the position

```
ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
```

i get the error unreachable code hope anybody can help me thx.

Comment: Most likely it is because it's contained in some sort of an if, if-else, or switch statement from which you return early without any chance for this code to execute. Without seeing the complete method it's difficult to tell.

Comment: yep, Levon is right, there must be some part of code that excludes the next code to be reached ever. By the way, if You are playing short sounds, use SoundPool instead of MediaPlayer....

Answer (score 1):

Create "raw" folder under res put the [Audio format supported by Android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats.html) put below code in your click event.

and

> ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

put under on create method in your class/ Activity

```
                        MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.camera);
                        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                mp.release();
                            }

                        });
                        mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
final MediaPlayer mpButtonClick;
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mpButtonClick  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.ba);
        mpButtonClick.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue